# Remove duplicates in array, zero padding at end

Tags: java, arrays

I have a task, to remove duplicates in array, what by "remove" means to shift elements down by `1`, and making the last element equal to `0`,
so if I have `int[] array = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2};` output should be like:
`1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0` 
I tried this logic:

```
public class ArrayDuplicates {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] array = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2};
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(deleteArrayDuplicates(array)));
        }

        public static int[] deleteArrayDuplicates(int[] array) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                    if (array[i] == array[j]) { //this is for comparing elements
                        for (; i > 0; i--) {
                            array[j + 1] = array[j]; //this is for shifting
                        }
                        array[array.length - 1] = 0; //making last element equal to "0"
                    }
                }
            }
            return array;
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work.. Is anyone familiar with a right solution?
I appreciate your assistance and attention very much.

Comment: @PatrickParker The input is not sorted, the final element is a `2`.

Comment: Have a closer look at your shift code. Did you use the correct index variable there? Is the shift direction correct? Single stepping with a debugger may help to detect such problems.

Comment: @Henry thank you Sir, actually you helped me very much, I found out what is debugger for myself.. I used a "debugger" in my head before for so long time, such an idiot haha.. Now life is easier, best wishes!

Comment: @artshakhov I've updated my answer with a suggestion; please have a look. Also, don't forget to accept an answer since it was solved now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@artshakhov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6877790/artshakhov):
Here is my approach, which is pretty much close enough to what you've found but using a bit fewer operations...

```
private static int[] deleteArrayDuplicates(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if (array[i] == NEUTRAL) continue; //if zero is a valid input value then don't waste time with it
        int idx = i + 1;  //no need for third cycle, just use memorization for current shifting index.
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                array[j] = NEUTRAL;
            } else {
                array[idx++] = array[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Your Code:**

In short, the approach you have chosen calls for a third loop variable, k, to represent the index that is currently being shifted left by 1 position.

- `i` - the current unique item's position
- `j` - the current position being tested for equality with unique item at `i`
- `k` - the current position being shifted left due to erasure at `j`

---

**Suggestion:**

A more efficient approach would be to eliminate the repetitive left shifting which occurs each time a duplicate is found and instead keep track of an offset based on the number of duplicates found:

```
private static int[] deleteArrayDuplicates(int[] array) {
    int dupes = 0; // total duplicates
    // i - the current unique item's position
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1 - dupes; i++) {
        int idupes = 0; // duplicates for current value of i
        // j - the current position being tested for equality with unique item at i
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length - dupes; j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                idupes++;
                dupes++;
            } else if(idupes > 0){
                array[j-idupes] = array[j];
            }
        }
    }
    if(dupes > 0) {
        Arrays.fill(array, array.length-dupes, array.length, 0);
    }
    return array;
}
```

This has similar complexity to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51561013/7098259) posted by [dbl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2185630/dbl), although it should be slightly faster due to eliminating some extra loops at the end. Another advantage is that this code doesn't rely on any assumptions that the input should not contain zeroes, unlike that answer.

Answer (score 1):

*I just wrote the following code to answer your question. I tested it and I am getting the output you expected. If there are any special cases I may have missed, I apologize but it seemed to work for a variety of inputs including yours.*

The idea behind is that we will be using a hash map to keep track if we have already seen a particular element in our array as we are looping through the array. If the map already contains that element- meaning we have already seen that element in our array- we just keep looping. However, if it is our first time seeing that element, we will update the element at the index where j is pointing to the element at the index where i is pointing to and then increment j.

So basically through the j pointer, we are able to move all the distinct elements to the front of the array while also making sure it is in the same order as it is in our input array.

Now after the first loop, our j pointer points to the first repeating element in our array. We can just set i to j and loop through the rest of the array, making them zero.

The time complexity for this algorithm is O(N). The space complexity is O(N) because of the hash table. There is probably a way to do this in O(N) time, O(1) space.

```
public static int[] deleteArrayDuplicates(int[] array) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (map.containsKey(array[i])) {
                    continue;
            }
            else {
                map.put(array[i],1);
                array[j] = array[i];
                j++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = j; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = 0;
        }
        return array;
    }
```

Let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: @artshakhov no problem! Glad to help out :)

Answer (score 1):

Spent a couple of hours trying to find a solution for my own, and created something like this:

```
public static int[] deleteArrayDuplicates(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j] == array[i]) { //this is for comparing elements
                int tempIndex = j;
                while (tempIndex + 1 < array.length) {
                    array[tempIndex] = array[tempIndex + 1]; //this is for shifting elements down/left by "1"
                    array[array.length - 1] = 0; //making last element equal to "0"
                    tempIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Code is without any API-helpers, but seems like is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int a[]={1,1,1,2,3,4,5};
    int b[]=new int[a.length];
    int top=0;
    for( int i : a )
    {
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0;j<top;j++)
        {
            if(i == b[j])
                count+=1;
        }
        if(count==0)
        {
            b[top]=i;
            top+=1;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0 ; i < b.length ; i++ )
        System.out.println( b[i] );
}
```

**Explanation:**

Create an another array **( b )** of same size of the given array.Now just include only the unique elements in the array **b**. Add the elements of array **a** to array **b** only if that element is not present in **b**.

Comment: Dumping a bunch of code without any explanation does not really help the OP to learn how to program.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class StackOverFlow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int[] array = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2};
   Set<Integer> set=new HashSet<>();
        for (int anArray : array) {
            set.add(anArray);
        }
        int[] a=new int[array.length];
        int i=0;
        for (Integer s:set) {
            a[i]=s;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

Hope this simple one may help you.
Make use of Set which doesn't allow duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

We can use **ARRAYLIST** and **Java-8 Streams** features to get the output.

```
public static int[] deleteArrayDuplicates(int[] array) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.stream(array).boxed().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()));
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (i < list.size()) {
                array[i] = list.get(i);
            } else {
                array[i] = 0;
            }
        }

        return array;
    }
```

---

**OUTPUT**

[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]